# Javascript cookies duration

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am using this function to read and write a cookie with a little php in it and its working fine. But I need to add duration of 7 days in it. Can anyone plz let me know where and how I can add it as I am a beginner in javascript and dont have any clue to update this code.

```
        <script language="javascript">
        writeCookie();
        function writeCookie()
        {
            the_cookie = document.cookie;
            if(the_cookie)
            {
                the_cookie = "PixelRatio="+window.devicePixelRatio+";"+the_cookie;
                document.cookie = the_cookie;

                if(window.devicePixelRatio > 1)
                {
                    location = '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>';
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Good resource for beginners at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: most of the stuff on w3schools is ok. but you shouldn't trust it 100%. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: i have used their cookie example. it works good though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any one of the following **attribute to set the duration for cookie**.

**Expires** - A date when the cookie will expire and get thrown away.
for example, today is 26th march 2013, If you want to set the duaration for 7 days, the code is as below 
 `document.cookie="acookie=avalue; expires=Tue, 02 Apr 2013 23:59:59 GMC";`

**Max-Age** - A number representing seconds until expiration. we have to calculate the seconds for days. example for 7 days duration is (60*60*24*7), the code is as follows

```
document.cookie="acookie=avalue; max-age=604800 ";
```

**Note** : Some browsers do not support Max-Age attribute. On browsers that do support it, if Max-Age and the Expires attribute are both set, Max-Age has precedence over Expires.